# Download file using Nodejs and Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, http, download

Download using Express and Angular!

I am using expressjs for backend API to write API download:

This is my express code:

```
app.get('/download/:file(*)',(req, res) => {

var file = req.params.file;

var fileLocation = path.join('./uploads',file);

console.log(fileLocation);

res.download(fileLocation, file);

});
```

In .ts file of Angular i write code to download as below:

```
public download(fileName: string): void {

var user = this._authService.getUser();

var token = JSON.parse(user).token || this.__authService.token;

var url = `${supportURL}/api/download/` + fileName;

const httpOptions = {

headers: new HttpHeaders({

'responseType': 'blob',

'Content-Type': 'application/json',

'Authorization': token

})

};

this._httpClient.get(url, httpOptions).subscribe(res => {

window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(res));

});

}
```

In html file I called like this:

```
<a (click) = "downloadFile(item.filename)"> Download</a>
```

But when I click on download, it's not download file, it's not showing any error but cannot download file. I dont know why? When debug at network console mode it's also show the image that I want download but cannot download, what I am wrong? Please tell me how. Thanks you so much

Comment: Anyone, someone? Plz